# How to implement "do something when meeting <EOS>"

Tags: python, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, machine-translation

The token `<EOS>` is ubiquitously used in NLP. As I haven't used it, the implementation of conditioning on it is a bit unclear to me. Could anyone provide a snippet of Python code. (If statements may be used.)

Example 1: There is a sequence of words with some `<EOS>` tokens interpolated. This sequence goes through a RNN to get encoded. Whenever encounters `<EOS>`, the timestep outputs its state.

Example 2: a machine translation task. When meets `<EOS>`, it stops generating tokens.

Answer (score 1):

The EOS token is important for the decoder as well: the explicit "end" token allows the decoder to emit arbitrary-length sequences. The decoder will tell us when it's done emitting tokens: without an "end" token, we would have no idea when the decoder is done talking to us and continuing to emit tokens will produce gibberish.

So for examples given, I have this snippet from [image captioning](https://github.com/luulinh90s/Show-Attend-and-Tell-Pytorch-Implementation/blob/master/eval.py) which is relative to machine translation:

```
        # Which sequences are incomplete (didn't reach <end>)?
        incomplete_inds = [ind for ind, next_word in enumerate(next_word_inds) if
                           next_word != word_map['<end>']]
        complete_inds = list(set(range(len(next_word_inds))) - set(incomplete_inds))
```

Here the token `<end>` is similar to `<EOS>`. This snippet is looking for the `<end>` token when generating caption for an image. Of course, we want to know when to stop, and the length of the caption is predefined for the boundary of caption for an image is known in advance in training step.